# ajax json not passing values to spring controller

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am sending an Json object to the controller using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
         url:  "/cart/add.json",
         type: "POST",
         data:{ 'json': event.data},          

    });
```

and the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/add.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addToCartJson(@RequestParam("json") final String jsonString, final Model model,
        final BindingResult bindingErrors)
```

I am getting 400 bad request.

> Error: "HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'json' is not
>   present"

Any Inputs?
Thanks,In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side want to string parameter but client side send to object. JSON.stringfy will be used converts object to string.To bind a json you will need to create a single class holding all your parameters and use the @RequestBody annotation instead of @RequestParam.

Ajax method is rewriting:

```
$.ajax({
         url:  "/cart/add.json",
         type: "POST",
         processData: false,
          data:  JSON.stringify({
               "json":  event.data
      }),
```

Controller action part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addEvent(@RequestBody EventData eventData){ 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the parameter json, you can try the below;

```
$.ajax({
            url:  "/cart/add.json",
            type: "POST",
            data:{ 'json=':event.data}
        });
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +